# segmentation fault ( core dumped )

Tags: c++, arrays, linux, segmentation-fault, uart

I'm trying to receive 9 float data using UART, every float is sent in the form XXX.XX. So I'm going to receive 5*9 =45 informations.

I tried to make the data received in a array of 45 char then I can do what I want with this array, but I get this famous error when i run my application : **Segmentation fault (core dumped**)

my code is

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <wiringSerial.h>
using namespace std;
int main (){
    int fd;
    float courant;
    float voltage;
    float activepower;
    float reactivepower;
    float apparentpower;
    float powerfactor;
    float frequency;
    float temperature;
    float indexIns;
    string courantC;
    string voltageC;
    string activepowerC;
    string reactivepowerC;
    string apparentpowerC;
    string powerfactorC;
    string frequencyC;
    string temperatureC;
    string indexinsC;

    char receivedData[45];
    int i=0;
    if ((fd = serialOpen("/dev/ttyS1",9600)) < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Unable to open serial device %s\n",strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }
    // Loop , getting and printing characters

    for (int j=0; j<45; j++)
    {
        i = serialGetchar(fd);
        receivedData[j] = char(i);

        if (j = 44) {
            j = 0;

            courantC = receivedData[0]+receivedData[1]+receivedData[2]+"." + receivedData[3]+receivedData[4];
            voltageC = receivedData[5]+receivedData[6]+receivedData[7]+"." + receivedData[8]+receivedData[9];
            activepowerC = receivedData[10]+receivedData[11]+receivedData[12]+"." + receivedData[13]+receivedData[14];
            reactivepowerC = receivedData[15]+receivedData[16]+receivedData[17]+"." + receivedData[18]+receivedData[19];
            apparentpowerC = receivedData[20]+receivedData[21]+receivedData[22]+"." + receivedData[23]+receivedData[24];
            powerfactorC = receivedData[25]+receivedData[26]+receivedData[27]+"." + receivedData[28]+receivedData[29];
            frequencyC = receivedData[30]+receivedData[31]+receivedData[32]+"." + receivedData[33]+receivedData[34];
            temperatureC = receivedData[35]+receivedData[36]+receivedData[37]+"." + receivedData[38]+receivedData[39];
            indexinsC = receivedData[40]+receivedData[41]+receivedData[42]+"." + receivedData[43]+receivedData[44];

           
        }
        printf("a=%c ", char(i));

        fflush(stdout);
```

The command used to compile

```
gcc receiveData.cpp -o receiveData -lwiringPi -lpthread -lstdc++
```

Comment: Please improve your formatting, it is very hard to read your code.

Comment: Think about `if (j=44)` and what's really happening here.

Comment: Why do you try to add characters (or integers, characters are integers in C) with a const array (`"."`)? This makes no sense and probably causes UB. What are you trying to do? I think you should learn what are arrays, pointers and what adding integers to it does first.

Comment: Furthermore, `receivedData[0]+receivedData[1]` etc. doesn't create a string, it just adds integer values.

Comment: your code is C with `std::string`. Read about [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) and your life will be easier if you realize that C and C++ are different languages (although you can write non-idiomatic c++ that is also valid C)

Comment: @idclev463035818 It is C++, i do not see how you think that code is C. It uses many things that are the same in C but should be done different in C++, but it is still C++. It is also tagged C++, so this part is correct.

Comment: for starters you should use the c++ headers `<cfoo>` instead of the c headers `<foo.h>`

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 if OP had used `std::string` consistently they would not face the problem, other than `std::string` its all C

Comment: @idclev463035818 It is bad C++, but it is still C++ and not C. `int main()` is also C++ and not allowed in C.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 it was a well intended tip to OP. I didnt claim that this is **the** problem with the code, maybe I didn't make that clear enough

Comment: Actually, why are you doing the `if (j == 44)` part inside the loop? Why not simply use the loop to read all bytes, then *after* the loop take the data you have read and separate it into the different values needed. That would simplify your code a little, and remove one serious bug (that right now leads to *undefined behavior*).

Comment: `c1 + "." + c2` is not string concatenation when `c1` and `c2` are not strings, but chars.

Comment: Why do you link to wiringPi and pthread? You do not use this libraries.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
courantC = receivedData[0]+receivedData[1]+receivedData[2]+"." + receivedData[3]+receivedData[4];
```

causes undefined behavior (UB) and is probably the cause of the segment fault. In this line you have an array of `char`, this here `"."`, with 2 chars, `'.'` and `'\0'`. This array is stored somewhere. When you use it like this it decays to a pointer that points at the start of the array.
The rest are all `char`, which are integers in C. They are added together and added to the pointer pointing to the array `"."`.
This pointer then points to some unknown memory region which is accessed by the `String` class to be copied to `courantC`. But accessing the region causes UB.